# MySQL Insert Database error

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to run a command to add items to a items table. I used MySQL to run query and used MySQL for database.

Here's the Structure:

```
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID               | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name             | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| TypeID           | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| RarityID         | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| IconImageID      | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| SpriteMapID      | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Resistance       | int(3)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Attack           | int(3)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Speediness       | int(3)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| GoldFinder       | int(3)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| TresureHunting   | int(3)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CreatureResearch | int(3)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| AttackDuration   | int(3)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| RemedyMastery    | int(3)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| AttackAccuracy   | int(3)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| AttackMastery    | int(3)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CriticalStrike   | int(3)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Sell             | int(5)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Buy              | int(5)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| LevelID          | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Query:

```
 INSERT INTO `Items` (Name,TypeID,RarityID,IconImageID,SpriteMapID,Resistance,Attack,Speediness,GoldFinder,TresureHunting,CreatureResearch,AttackDuration,RemedyMasteryAttackAccuracy,AttackMastery,CriticalStrike,Sell,Buy,LevelID)VALUES(
 ('Small Red Tonic', 1, 1, 22, NULL, 25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 50, 20, 1),
 ('Medium Red Tonic', 1, 2, 23, NULL, 100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 150, 60, 15),
 ('Large Red Tonic', 1, 3, 24, NULL,  400,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 500, 200, 30),
 ('Small Blue Tonic', 1, 1, 25, NULL, 0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 50, 20, 1),
 ('Medium Blue Tonic', 1, 2, 26, NULL, 0,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 150, 60, 15),
 ('Large Blue Tonic', 1, 3, 27, NULL, 0,400,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 500, 200, 30),
 ('Small Purple Tonic', 1, 1, 28, NULL, 25,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 75, 30, 1),
 ('Medium Purple Tonic', 1, 2, 29, NULL, 100,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 250, 90, 15),
 ('Large Purple Tonic', 1, 3, 30, NULL, 400,400,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 800, 250, 30),
 ('Turnip', 2, 1, 31, NULL, 10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, NULL, 20, 1),
 ('Potato', 2, 2, 32, NULL, 25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, NULL, 20, 1),
 ('Apple', 2, 2, 33, NULL, 25,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, NULL, 20, 10),
 ('Watermelon', 2, 3, 34, NULL, 50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, NULL, 20, 1),
 ('Cheese', 2, 3, 35, NULL,  50,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 50, NULL, 10),
 ('Training Jacket', 3, 1, 36, 37, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, 20, 1),
 ('Training Bandanna', 4, 1, 38, 39, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, 20, 1),
 ('Training Trowsers', 5, 1, 40, 41, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, 20, 1),
 ('Training Trainers', 6, 1, 42, 43, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, 20, 1),
 ('Training Staff', 7, 1, 44, 45,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, 20, 1),
 ('Basic Farmer''s Jursy', 3, 1, 46, 47, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 20, 2),
 ('Basic Farmer''s Jursy', 4, 1, 48, 49, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 20, 2),
 ('Basic Farmer''s Trowsers', 5, 1, 50, 51 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 20, 2),
 ('Basic Farmer''s Trainers', 6, 1, 52, 53, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 20, 2),
 ('Basic Farmer''s Staff', 7, 1, 54, 55, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 60, 20, 2),
 ('Elegant Chef''s Top', 3, 1, 56, 57, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 75, 25, 3),
 ('Elegant Chef''s Hat', 4, 1, 58, 59, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 75, 25, 3),
 ('Elegant Chef''s Trowsers', 5, 1, 60, 61, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 75, 25, 3),
 ('Elegant Chef''s Shoes', 6, 1, 62, 63 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 75, 25, 3),
 ('Elegant Chef''s Staff', 7, 1, 64, 65 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 75, 25, 3),
 ('Traditional Hunter''s Top', 3, 1, 66, 67 , 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 125, 40, 4),
 ('Traditional Hunter''s Hat', 4, 1, 68, 69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 125, 40, 4),
 ('Traditional Hunter''s Trowsers', 5, 1, 70, 71, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 125, 40, 4),
 ('Traditional Hunter''s Shoes', 6, 1, 72, 73 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 125, 40, 4),
 ('Traditional Hunter''s Staff', 7, 1, 74, 75 , 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 150, 45, 4),
 ('Critical Coaches Top', 3, 1, 76, 77, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 250, 80, 5),
 ('Critical Coaches Hat', 4, 1, 78, 79 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 250, 80, 5),
 ('Critical Coaches Trowsers', 5, 1, 80, 81, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 250, 80, 5),
 ('Critical Coaches Shoes', 6, 1, 82, 83 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 250, 80, 5),
 ('Critical Coaches Staff', 7, 1, 84, 85 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 250, 80, 5));
```

When I run the Insert command it gives the following error :
`ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

What is the error ? Where is my wrong ?

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes in the text. escape the single quotes inside the text by using it twice.

Comment: @GurV Just updated query but comes up with same result

Comment: don't enclose brackets inside brackets `values ((),())`. Use `values (), ()`. Then, number of column listed in your insert part are lesser than number of column in your data

Comment: Does mySQL support a mass insert like that in the first place?

Comment: @xQbert Yes it does.

Comment: Remove the double (( at start and the ending ))  should only be 1 at each place.   Ending `, 80, 5));` should be `, 80, 5);` and beginning `(
 ('Small` should be `('Small `  Tested on [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4b6c4/1) got error: ***Operand should contain 1 column(s).***  removing double (( and )) eliminated error.

Comment: I don't believe this would give you the error you are getting but `RemedyMasteryAttackAccuracy` is missing the comma in between. Also I believe the number of fields and the number of insert values are off you may want to recount.

Comment: Thanks Really helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming everything else is correct:

```
To eliminate the Operand should contain 1 column(s). error.
```

Simply remove the outer ()'s surrounding the values.

However there are other errors you only have 18 columns and 21 columns.

```
INSERT INTO `Items` (Name,TypeID,RarityID,IconImageID,SpriteMapID,Resistance,Attack,Speediness,GoldFinder,TresureHunting,CreatureResearch,AttackDuration,RemedyMasteryAttackAccuracy,AttackMastery,CriticalStrike,Sell,Buy,LevelID)
VALUES 
 ('Small Red Tonic', 1, 1, 22, NULL, 25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 50, 20, 1),
 ('Medium Red Tonic', 1, 2, 23, NULL, 100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 150, 60, 15),
 ('Large Red Tonic', 1, 3, 24, NULL,  400,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 500, 200, 30),
 ('Small Blue Tonic', 1, 1, 25, NULL, 0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 50, 20, 1),
 ('Medium Blue Tonic', 1, 2, 26, NULL, 0,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 150, 60, 15),
 ('Large Blue Tonic', 1, 3, 27, NULL, 0,400,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 500, 200, 30),
 ('Small Purple Tonic', 1, 1, 28, NULL, 25,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 75, 30, 1),
 ('Medium Purple Tonic', 1, 2, 29, NULL, 100,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 250, 90, 15),
 ('Large Purple Tonic', 1, 3, 30, NULL, 400,400,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 800, 250, 30),
 ('Turnip', 2, 1, 31, NULL, 10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, NULL, 20, 1),
 ('Potato', 2, 2, 32, NULL, 25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, NULL, 20, 1),
 ('Apple', 2, 2, 33, NULL, 25,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, NULL, 20, 10),
 ('Watermelon', 2, 3, 34, NULL, 50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, NULL, 20, 1),
 ('Cheese', 2, 3, 35, NULL,  50,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 50, NULL, 10),
 ('Training Jacket', 3, 1, 36, 37, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, 20, 1),
 ('Training Bandanna', 4, 1, 38, 39, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, 20, 1),
 ('Training Trowsers', 5, 1, 40, 41, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, 20, 1),
 ('Training Trainers', 6, 1, 42, 43, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, 20, 1),
 ('Training Staff', 7, 1, 44, 45,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, 20, 1),
 ('Basic Farmer''s Jursy', 3, 1, 46, 47, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 20, 2),
 ('Basic Farmer''s Jursy', 4, 1, 48, 49, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 20, 2),
 ('Basic Farmer''s Trowsers', 5, 1, 50, 51 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 20, 2),
 ('Basic Farmer''s Trainers', 6, 1, 52, 53, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 20, 2),
 ('Basic Farmer''s Staff', 7, 1, 54, 55, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 60, 20, 2),
 ('Elegant Chef''s Top', 3, 1, 56, 57, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 75, 25, 3),
 ('Elegant Chef''s Hat', 4, 1, 58, 59, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 75, 25, 3),
 ('Elegant Chef''s Trowsers', 5, 1, 60, 61, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 75, 25, 3),
 ('Elegant Chef''s Shoes', 6, 1, 62, 63 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 75, 25, 3),
 ('Elegant Chef''s Staff', 7, 1, 64, 65 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 75, 25, 3),
 ('Traditional Hunter''s Top', 3, 1, 66, 67 , 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 125, 40, 4),
 ('Traditional Hunter''s Hat', 4, 1, 68, 69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 125, 40, 4),
 ('Traditional Hunter''s Trowsers', 5, 1, 70, 71, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 125, 40, 4),
 ('Traditional Hunter''s Shoes', 6, 1, 72, 73 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 125, 40, 4),
 ('Traditional Hunter''s Staff', 7, 1, 74, 75 , 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 150, 45, 4),
 ('Critical Coaches Top', 3, 1, 76, 77, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 250, 80, 5),
 ('Critical Coaches Hat', 4, 1, 78, 79 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 250, 80, 5),
 ('Critical Coaches Trowsers', 5, 1, 80, 81, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 250, 80, 5),
 ('Critical Coaches Shoes', 6, 1, 82, 83 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 250, 80, 5),
 ('Critical Coaches Staff', 7, 1, 84, 85 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 250, 80, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just fired this query and It worked Perfectly well..!

```
INSERT INTO `Items` (`ID`, `Name`, `TypeID`, `RarityID`, `IconImageID`,`SpriteMapID`, `Resistance`, `Attack`, `Speediness`, `GoldFinder`, `TresureHunting`, `CreatureResearch`, `AttackDuration`, `RemedyMastery`, `AttackAccuracy`, `AttackMastery`, `CriticalStrike`, `Sell`, `Buy`, `LevelID`) VALUES (NULL, 'Small Red Tonic', '1', '1', '22', NULL, '25', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '50', '20', '1'), (NULL, 'Medium Red Tonic', '1', '2', '23', NULL, '100', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '150', '60', '15');
```

You can Simply add more values by seeing the above Syntax by Appending and doing the required changes in the above Code..!

The First Very Basic Mistake which i found in your query is that there is no comma between the two column names:

```
,RemedyMasteryAttackAccuracy,
```

shoukd be

```
,RemedyMastery,AttackAccuracy,
```

On line one..!!

and Try executing this one. I hope it helps.!